# SQL Server : Union with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I want to union two querys with multiple columns like recommended in other posts like this

```
select NULL AS Col1
       ,NULL AS Col2
       ,NULL AS Col3
       ,Col4
       ,Col5

union 

select Col1
       ,Col2
       ,Col3
       ,NULL AS Col4
       ,NULL AS Col5
```

I get:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 
---------------------------------
NULL | NULL | NULL |  2   |  0
 7   |  3   |  4   | NULL | NULL
```

is there any way to combine the rows?
Because of that alias I cant group by the columns.

I want to get

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 
---------------------------------
  7  |  3   |   4  |  2   |  0
```

Comment: Its not clear. Edit your question and add a sample of results you want

Comment: Are you sure `UNION` is what you're trying to achieve here? I assume there's more than one row coming from each query? If so, how are the rows meant to be "matched up" to become a smaller number of output rows?

Comment: Without a better example (i.e. using multiple rows, having a `FROM` clause, etc), we're all just stumped why your query isn't just `SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5` - can you not see why your presentation is confusing?

Answer (score 1):

As per DhruvJoshi answer, You can try like this,

```
SELECT B.Col1
    ,B.col2
    ,B.col3
    ,A.col4
    ,A.col5
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS Col1
        ,NULL AS Col2
        ,NULL AS Col3
        ,2 AS Col4
        ,0 AS Col5
    ) A
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 7 AS Col1
        ,3 AS Col2
        ,4 AS Col3
        ,NULL AS Col4
        ,NULL AS Col5
    ) B
```

Comment: yes I got it with that. Nice work. The only change I make is to use a INNER JOIN to become 5 columns. With that OUTER JOIN u will become 10 rows.

Comment: Please voteup or select any one of the answer which best suits you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CROSS JOIN for your use case like below

`select Col1 ,Col2 ,Col3, Col4 ,Col5  from tblA CROSS JOIN tblB`

[See working SQL demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/642a7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Col1) AS 'Col1',  SUM(Col2) AS 'Col2', SUM(Col3) AS 'Col3', SUM(Col4) AS 'Col4', SUM(Col5) AS 'Col5' FROM
(
select NULL AS Col1
       ,NULL AS Col2
       ,NULL AS Col3
       ,Col4
       ,Col5

union 

select Col1
       ,Col2
       ,Col3
       ,NULL AS Col4
       ,NULL AS Col5
) A
```